# Asynchronous messages golang

Tags: asynchronous, go, channel, goroutine

I have a golang server doing something like this:
    package main

```
func main() {
    for {
        c := listener.Accept()
        go handle(c)
    }
}

...
func handle(c net.Conn) {
    m := readMessage(c)    // func(net.Conn)Message
    r := processMessage(m) //func(Message)Result
    sendResult(c, r)       // func(net.Conn,Result)
}
```

Which reads and writes messages synchronously. What I need now is to send messages asynchronously through a given open connection, I know a channel can be used by I'm kind of lost.

This is my idea:

```
...
func someWhereElese(c chan Result) {
    // generate a message and a result
    r := createResultFromSomewhere()
    c <- r // send the result through the channel
}
```

And modify my handle to use that same channel instead

```
func handle(c net.Conn, rc chan Result) {
    m := readMessage(c)    // func(net.Conn)Message
    r := processMessage(m) //func(Message)Result
    //sendResult(c, r)       // func(net.Conn,Result)
    rc <- r
}
```

And here's where my confusion lies.

The result channel should be created and it should have a connection where to send whatever it receives

```
func doSend(c net.Con, rc chan Result) {
    r := rc          // got a result channel
    sendResult(c, r) // send it through the wire
}
```

But where should that channel be created? In the main loop?

```
func main() {
    ...
    for {
        c := l.Accept()
        rc := make(chan Result)
        go doSend(c, rc)
    }
}
```

What about the read? Should it go in it's own channel/gorutine?
If I need to broadcast to n clients, should I keep a slice of result channels? a slice of connections?

I'm kind of confused here, but I feel I'm close.

Comment: Start here: http://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide. The key to your problem is using `select` to watch an incoming connection channel, a response channel, and maybe a quit channel. Depending on your anticipated load, creating one goroutine per request may be fine; or you may need to create a pool. But you'll understand the right questions better once you go through Go Concurrency Patterns. See also http://blog.golang.org/advanced-go-concurrency-patterns and especially the "related articles" at the end. Understanding `select` is one of the great "oh, that's how Go works!" moments.

Comment: @RobNapier Uhm... I read through the slides before and I kind of get them but not quite. I'll go through them again in a few moments. Meanwhile I managed to have a small program, can you comment on it if you see anything particularly dangerous?

Comment: OK; I may have misunderstood what you meant by "asynchronous." I had assumed that multiple requests and responses would happen on the same connection (interleaving requests). You seem to mean that you want to stream data as the reader gets it. This is possibly a little more parallel than just reading two bytes and writing two bytes in a single goroutine. You may want to look at `golang.org/x/text/transform` for this purpose, together with `io.Copy()`. (Sorry I'm not more helpful with actual code here; it was an interesting question, but I don't have time this minute to help extensively.)

Comment: No, you're right. This is the first step though. Without the channels I wasn't able to make another write between reads, and the flow will lock until I had something else to read.

Now with this change, I'm able to "broadcast" messages coming from other connections without having to wait for a read to happen.

Next step will be read from a single goroutine and/or use a pool to avoid creating a goroutine for each open connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program seems to solve my immediate question

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "log"

    "net"
)

var rcs []chan int = make([]chan int,0)


func main() {
    a, e := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ":8082")
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    l, e := net.ListenTCP("tcp", a)
    for {
        c, e := l.Accept()
        if e != nil {
            log.Fatal(e)
        }
        rc := make(chan int)
        go read(c, rc)
        go write(c, rc)
        rcs = append(rcs, rc)
        // simulate broacast
        log.Println(len(rcs))
        if len(rcs) > 5 {
            func() {
                for _, v := range rcs {
                    log.Println("sending")
                    select {
                    case v <- 34:
                        log.Println("done sending")
                    default:
                        log.Println("didn't send")
                    }
                }
            }()
        }
    }
}
func read(c net.Conn, rc chan int) {
    h := make([]byte, 2)
    for {
        _, err := c.Read(h)
        if err != nil {
            rc <- -1
        }
        var v int16
        binary.Read(bytes.NewReader(h[:2]), binary.BigEndian, &v)
        rc <- int(v)
    }
}
func write(c net.Conn, rc chan int) {
    for {
        r := <-rc
        o := []byte{byte(r * 2)}
        c.Write(o)
    }
}
```